# npm protocol error after yo hubot command

Tags: node.js, npm

I've been on this for about a day now. I'm running ubuntu/trusty64 on virtual box via vagrant. Each time i try to scaffold a new hubot project with yo hubot command, hubot gets installed but with npm errors. I really can't figure out what the issue is.

i installed node, npm, hubot and coffee script via the shell. here is what my provision.sh script looks like

```
#!/bin/bash

# update package libraries
apt-get -y update

# install curl if it is not already installed
apt-get -y  install curl

# if nodejs is not installed...
type node >/dev/null 2>&1 || if [[ $? != 0 ]]; then
    # we install it
    curl -sL http://deb.nodesource.com/setup_5.x | sudo -E bash -
    apt-get -y install nodejs

    # update npm
    npm install -g npm

fi

command -v hubot &>/dev/null || {
    npm install -g hubot coffee-script
}

# install yeoman for hubot
command -v yo &>/dev/null || {
    npm install -g yo generator-hubot
}
```

The nodejs version installed is v5.11.1
The npm version installed is v3.8.6

After installation, the next step is to scaffold hubot. This is done by creating a new directory.I named the directory myhubot. When I switch into the directory and type the command: Yo hubot --default, it begins installation but it ends with this error:

```
13519 error Linux 3.13.0-86-generic
13520 error argv "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "hubot" "hubot-scripts" "hubot-diagnostics" "hubot-help" "hubot-heroku-keepalive" "hubot-google-images" "hubot-google-translate" "hubot-pugme" "hubot-maps" "hubot-redis-brain" "hubot-rules" "hubot-shipit" "--save"
13521 error node v5.11.1
13522 error npm  v3.8.6
13523 error path ../coffee-script/bin/coffee
13524 error code EPROTO
13525 error errno -71
13526 error syscall symlink
13527 error EPROTO: protocol error, symlink '../coffee-script/bin/coffee' -> '/vagrant/myhubot/node_modules/.bin/coffee'
13528 error If you need help, you may report this error at:
13528 error     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>
13529 verbose exit [ -71, true ]
```

Apparently, even after the error log, if type the "hubot" command, I'm logged 
into the hubot shell. But then, when i ping hubot, I don't get a reply.

[Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/dv7h0sq3rk3qzv1/npm-debug.txt?dl=0) is the full npm-debug log. 
I [think](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ycifkoes6iwf9tx/error.PNG?dl=0) this image too will be helpful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide the command(s) you issued and the errors you get in your question (and not via a link to some temporary resource). Perhaps some version information could be helpful as well.

Comment: @mkluwe thank you for the advice. I've added more detail to the question now. I hope it will be helpful for whoever wants to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error occurs because the `npm` command requires symlinks and it is not supported in Windows as referenced in this issue: https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/9901

You can fix this issue by following the steps outlined in this post: [Symbolic Links with Vagrant Windows](http://blog.rudylee.com/2014/10/27/symbolic-links-with-vagrant-windows/)

The steps are:

**Add a snippet to your VagrantFile to enable symlinks:**

```
config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |v|
    v.customize ["setextradata", :id, "VBoxInternal2/SharedFoldersEnableSymlinksCreate/v-root", "1"]
end
```

**Boot the Vagrant machine in Administrator mode**
This is to circumvent *Vagrant's* restriction on symbolic links.

Comment: Excellent. Works like a charm. Apparently the gist you referred me to: https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/9901 suggested --no-bin-links. But then, as I figured, --no-bin-links won't work with certain tools; making it a less desirable solution. I'll take circumventing Vagrant's restriction on symbolic as a far better fix. But if i may ask, since rsync doesn't use symbolic links, could it be a fix too?

Comment: It could. The difficulty would be its integration with the tool (yeoman).